# Self signed certificate process

Tags: cryptography, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, self-signed-certificate

How does a certificate self signed process work? From requesting a self signed certificate, who does it go to and who performs the signing? (End-to-end process)

Answer (score 0):

You do all the self-signed certificate things yourself.

Here is a PowerShell script that I have used in the past. Of course update the values to something that makes sense to you.

```
$myName = "Your Name"
$myEmail = "your@emaildomain.tld"
$certPassword = "password1234"

$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -Container test* -Subject "CN=$myName" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2","2.5.29.17={text}upn=$myEmail") -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(6)

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$certPassword" -Force -AsPlainText
$path = "cert:\localMachine\my\" + $cert.thumbprint

Export-PfxCertificate -cert $path -FilePath c:\temp\pdf\pdf.pfx -Password $pwd
```

I have used the self-signed certificate generated by that script to sign PDF files.  To see an example and context of how I have used this script, you can check out this blog post: https://www.leadtools.com/blog/document-imaging/pdf/csharp-java-code-digitally-sign-pdf-files-certificate/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create self-signed certificates by yourself. The best option would be PowerShell. With a single PowerShell cmdlet, you can do magic.

```
$Certificate=New-SelfSignedCertificate –Subject testing.com -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

Then you can export the created certificate to store it in your local machine for further use.

```
Export-Certificate -Cert $Certificate -FilePath "C:\$certname.cer"
```

You can create certificates with multiple properties and for various purposes. For more example, you can refer this blog: https://blog.admindroid.com/how-to-create-self-signed-certificate-using-powershell/